# Looking for Spanish writing that is humorous in nature to help with comprehension

Tags: recursos, humor

Apologies if this question isn't exactly in line with this forum, but I would appreciate some help if possible.

I have been doing some language exchange and have found that the use of humorous material is a good way to check for comprehension of some of the finer points of languages.

It is actually difficult to find materials from newspapers and other publicly available content online, so I am wondering if anyone has come across materials or resources of a humorous nature that I can use to test my comprehension and understanding of Spanish.

Here are some examples of what I am looking for (sorry but humor can be subjective to some degree):

> ¿Qué hace una abeja en el gimnasio? Zumba!
>
> ¿Qué hace el pez perezoso? ¡Nada!
>
> La nueva cocinera es un sol. ¿Cocina bien?  No, lo quema todo.
>
> ¿Cómo se escribe calcetines en inglés?  Eso sí que es
>
> Un tipo y una mujer en la playa:  “Y usted, ¿no nada nada?” “No traje
> traje.”

Comment: "sorry but humor can be subjective to some degree".  Humor *is* subjective, and is also cultural.  EG US humor is not UK humor is not Australian humor is not Japanese humor.

Comment: @PeterM I understand, but there are also aspects of humour that seem to be universal, like satire and poking fun at the absurdities of life and human behaviours regardless of language and culture, don't you think?

Comment: Except that those concepts are always seen through the lens of the culture that produced them.

Answer (score 3):

No sé qué tan ‘legal’ es responder a esto, pero acá van mis

**Top 5 audiovisuales** : todos se pueden encontrar en Youtube, aunque es contenido para adultos y probablemente algunos chistes sean difíciles de entender.

- [Guille Aquino](https://www.youtube.com/@GuilleAquino)
- [Luis Landriscina](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mbXYNoc2oI0)
- [Prestico](https://www.youtube.com/@Prestico)
- [Yayo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sxm_LTbU0hE)
- [Dr. Tangalanga](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xtEJACz4s_g)

**Top 5 literarios** : en esto soy mucho más infantil, porque hace mucho que ya no leo libros de humor.

- *Natacha* (todos los libros publicados), de Luis Pescetti
- *Nadie te creería*, de Luis Pescetti
- *Querido hijo: estás despedido*, de Jordi Sierra i Fabra
- *La rebelión de las palabras*, de Andrea Ferrari
- *¡Cuidado con el perro!*, de Liliana Cinetto

Todo va a depender de tus gustos, incluso es posible que a un nativo no le haga reír ni la mitad de los contenidos. Personalmente te diría que empecés por leer todos los libros de Pescetti, son historias que, a la vez, son realmente breves, sencillas y muy graciosas—o al menos lo fueron en mi infancia. Los demás siéntanse libres de publicar sus *tops*, no hagan quedar mal a sus países.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! Buscaré los libros de Pescetti :)

Answer (score 3):

An online source which might help is the satirical newspaper [El Mundo Today](https://www.elmundotoday.com/)

You get a certain number of views free per month and then have to subscribe. Any political humour in it is Spain-oriented which may be less help if you are living in one of the other Spanish-speaking countries.

Occasional articles used to be in Catalan but I have not seen one for a while.

I have no connection with the organisers, I just read it occasionally.

Comment: No entiendo nada de política española, pero me he reido mucho con los titulares.

Comment: Do you know of any cartoons that are in the newspapers by any chance? Because I think that will definitely be interesting and humorous.

Answer (score 3):

Ademés de las repuestas anteriores, el website gocomics tiene muchas caricaturas sindicadas en español.  Puedes verlas [aquí](https://www.gocomics.com/comics/espanol).

Comment: Perfecto, este es justo el tipo de cosas que estoy buscando. ¡Gracias por tu respuesta!

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for humorous and interesting cartoons, you should give a try to [Francisco Ibáñez](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Francisco_Ib%C3%A1%C3%B1ez#Obras)'s work. Specially Mortadelo y Filemón, Rompetechos and 13 Rue del percebe. These are child horiented comics, but also portray some of the best spanish stereotypes. I specially recomend Mortadelo y Filemón comics, as I grew up with them, like half of Spansih people.

Comment: That's great, I will try and find some of his work available online and see how much I can understand. I am just starting to understand some aspects of Spanish humour :)